# A strange trigonometric inequality

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I am trying to check that:
$$f(t) = t^2(t-3) + 2 e^{-t/2} + e^{t/2}\left(\sqrt{3} \sin \frac{\sqrt{3}t}{2} + \cos \frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2} \right) - e^{-t/2} \left(\sqrt{3} \sin \frac{\sqrt{3}t}{2} + 3\cos \frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2} \right)\ge 0$$
for  $ t \in [0, \infty)$ ( in fact  for $t\in \mathbb{R}$). This function [equals](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=InverseLaplaceTransform%5B%201%2F%28s%5E4%281%2Bs%2Bs%5E2%2Bs%5E3%2Bs%5E4%2Bs%5E5%29%29%2C%20s%2C%20t%5D) $6\times$ the inverse [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) of $$\phi(s) =\frac{1}{s^4(1+s+s^2+s^3+s^4+s^5)}= \frac{1}{s^4(1+s)(1-s+s^2)(1+s+s^2)}$$

I don't have a clean proof of the fact. Any feedback would be appreciated. Thank you for your interest!

$\bf{Note:}$ the exponent $5=6-1$ in $\phi$ is  chosen  since $6$ factors nicely and WA can calculate the inverse Laplace transform. The exponent $4$ is so that we get a positive result ( anything larger would work). We could instead use  $7=8-1$, or $11= 12-1$, and an exponent $m$. For $m$ large enough we get again a  positive $f(t)$. Here we are looking for $\phi(s)$ that are [completely monotone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein%27s_theorem_on_monotone_functions)

I tried looking at the Taylor expansion of $f(t)$. One could perhaps prove that is is alternating, so that shows the inequality for $t\le 0$. But we are interested in $t\ge 0$. It seems that the function $\frac{1}{f(t)}$ has a Taylor expansion at $t=0$ with positive coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

The conclude is wrong. Note
\begin{eqnarray}
f(t) &=& t^2(t-3) + 2 e^{-t/2} + e^{t/2}\left(\sqrt{3} \sin \frac{\sqrt{3}t}{2} + \cos \frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2} \right) - e^{-t/2} \left(\sqrt{3} \sin \frac{\sqrt{3}t}{2} + 3\cos \frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2} \right)\\
&=& t^2(t-3) + 2 e^{-t/2} + 2e^{t/2}\sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}t}{2}+\frac{\pi}{3} \right)  - e^{-t/2} \left(\sqrt{3} \sin \frac{\sqrt{3}t}{2} + 3\cos \frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2} \right).
\end{eqnarray}
Let $\frac{\sqrt{3}t_n}{2}+\frac{\pi}{3}=2n\pi-\frac{\pi}{4}$ (where $n$ is a positive integer). Then
$$ f(t_n)=t_n^2(t_n-3) + 2 e^{-t_n/2} - \sqrt2e^{t_n/2}-e^{-t_n/2} \left(\sqrt{3} \sin \frac{\sqrt{3}t_n}{2} + 3\cos \frac{\sqrt{3} t_n}{2} \right)$$
and hence $f(t_n)\to-\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Yes indeed, thank you very much! Great observation!